# I am getting this error SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence at eval (<anonymous>) error adding console log in the getStaticProps()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, console

**This is my page users.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const users = ({users}) => {
  return (
    <>    {
      users.map(user => {
        return <div key={user.id}> {user.name} </div>
      })
    }
    </>
  )
}



export default users


export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const users = await res.json()

    console.log("users", users)  

    return {
      props: {
        users,
      },
      // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
      // - When a request comes in
      // - At most once every 10 seconds
      revalidate: 10, // In seconds
    }
  }
```

**When I Run This I get this below error in my terminal, instead how can I see the users value in my terminal?**

```
`error - SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at oo_oo (webpack-internal:///./pages/users.js:50:14)
    at users (webpack-internal:///./pages/users.js:14:5)
    at renderWithHooks (C:\Users\udays\Documents\NEXTLEARN\next-pre-render\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)


`
```

I have tried to comment out

```
`   reactStrictMode: true,`
```

but it did not work.

Your Help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some error handling like such.

```js
const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
if (res.ok) {
  const users = await res.json()
  console.log("users", users)  
  return {
    props: {
      users,
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 10 seconds
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
} else {
  console.log('There was an error getting the data', res.status)
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the way you suggested and It is still the same.. On the browser I am seeing this error code below.

Server Error
SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages\users.js (37:47) @ oo_oo

  35 | }
  36 | }
> 37 | /* eslint-disable */;function oo_oo(){(0,eval)("'use strict';var _0x1d95d2=_0x4c2b;